# Why is my function in JS returning both results in the handler function

Tags: javascript

In **function readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp)**, my website (which returns a table) outputs both results of the handler, success and failure, even though the table is being displayed with no problems at all.

[image]

Notice below the "get search result" button, an error is being displayed from readyStateChangeHandler

```js
function makeAjaxQuery() {
  // create an XMLHttpRequest
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  // create a handler for the readyState change
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp);
  };
  // making query by async call
  xhttp.open("GET", "xxxxxxx-A3-Q6.json", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
// handler for the readyState change
function readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp) {
  if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
    // readyState = 4 means DONE
    //status = 200 means OK
    handleStatusSuccess(xhttp);
    console.log('success')
  } else {
    // status is NOT OK
    console.log('failure')
    handleStatusFailure(xhttp);
  }
}

// XMLHttpRequest failed
function handleStatusFailure(xhttp) {
  //display error message
  var displayDiv = document.getElementById("display");
  displayDiv.innerHTML = "XMLHttpRequest failed: status " + xhttp.status;
}
// XMLHttpRequest success
function handleStatusSuccess(xhttp) {
  var jsonText = xhttp.responseText;
  //parse the json into an object
  var obj = JSON.parse(jsonText);
  // display the object on the page
  displayObj(obj);
}

function displayObj(obj) {
  var table = "";
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    table +=
      "<tr><td>" + '<a href="' + obj.result.video[i].link + '"><img src="' + obj.result.video[i].image + '" width=200"' + '</a>' + "</td><td>" +
      '<span style="color:#DA3FA4; font-weight:bold; font-size: 30px;">' + obj.result.video[i].title + "</span>" + "<br/>" +
      '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 25px;">' + obj.result.video[i].channel + "</span>" + "<br/>" +
      '<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size: 25px;">' + obj.result.video[i].view + " views" + "</span>" + "<br/>" +
      '<span style="font-weight:bold; background-color: black; color:white"font-size: 25px;>' + obj.result.video[i].length + "</span>" + "</td></tr><td>";
  }
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = '<h1>Search results</h1><br><span style="font-size: 30px;">Search keyword: Mathematics</span><br>';
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}
const start = document.getElementById("getSearch");
start.addEventListener("click", function() {
  makeAjaxQuery()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess you get something in between the `if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {` for example 2 or 3 plus 200 [readystate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) - so for example use

```
xhttp.onload= function() {
  readyStateChangeHandler(xhttp);
};
```

or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)